# Making an overlay appear over a parent div, but below that div's child

Tags: css, z-index

I want an output like this:

[image: visual display of output]

The actual structure is:

```
<div class="container">   <!-- green -->
  <div class="overlay">   <!-- purple -->
  </div>

  <div class="parent">    <!-- red -->
      <div class="child"> <!-- lightblue -->
          Child
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have achieved it after half an hour of struggle via this CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay{
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.child {
    z-index: 100;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

([Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjXMR/1949/))

What I do not understand is: why is it not allowed to set `.parent`'s z-index value to anything? Because doing so immediately breaks this order. If I set `.parent{z-index: a;}` where `a` is an integer <= 1, then the purple overlay comes over the child, but if `a>=2`, then `.child` and `.parent` both come over `.overlay`.

But why does it break anything at all? I would at-least expect `z-index: 0;` to not break anything, since it is the ground level kind of thing. What am I missing?

Also, if I am working on a webpage where the `z-index` of `.parent` cannot be changed from its given integer value, because of other constraints of the page, is there any other way to insert an `.overlay` between the `.parent` and its `.child`? (the positioning and z-index of the `.overlay` is in my hands)

Comment: Because of _stacking contexts_. https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: check this to understand why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557595/z-index-problem-with-multi-layer-background/52557704#52557704 read the end of the answer